# bokeh serve --show myapp

Tags: python, bokeh

I try to run a simple bokeh app but after executing on terminal `"bokeh serve --show myapp"` I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'return_future' from 'tornado.concurrent' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py)
```

I have the latest versions of modules ( tornado bokeh etc.)

Comment: So you're using Bokeh version 1.0.4 and tornado 6.0.2? It works fine on my PC... You could try another version of tornado, as long as it's more recent than tornado 3.4.

Comment: Try running **pip install tornado==4.5.3**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error report when running bokeh version 0.13.0 and tornado version 6.0.2 . When downgrading my tornado version to 5.0.2 it works again.

to downgrade your tornado version, run in cmd:

```
pip install tornado==5.0.2
```